# How to structure apache virtual host and wsgi file for Flask application with python 3.10 on raspbian

Tags: python, linux, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

On a raspberry pi 3 I am trying to deploy a Flask application on apache server. This application is going to be accessible by a custom internal network domain called darts.loc.

The structure of the application is as following:

```
/var/www/darts
└── darts
    ├── dartsapp
    │   ├── api
    │   │   └── resources
    │   │  
    │   ├── static
    │   │   ├── css
    │   │   ├── fonts
    │   │   ├── images
    │   │   └── js
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   
    │   │      
    │   │          
    │   │           
    │   │           
    │   │           
    │   ├── uploads
    │   └── website
    └── venv
```

In /var/www/darts/darts I have an `__init__.py` file with the following content:

```
from dartsapp import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

What should I update in my darts.conf and darts.wsgi files so that I can get the application running?

The current structure is as following:

darts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerName darts.loc
                ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com

WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/darts/darts.wsgi
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
<Directory /var/www/darts/darts>
                         AddDefaultCharset utf-8
                         SetEnv PYTHONIOENCODING utf8

                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                        AllowOverride All
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>
                 Alias /dartsapp /var/www/darts/darts/dartsapp
                <Directory /var/www/darts/darts/dartsapp>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                        AllowOverride All
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>

                Alias /templates /var/www/darts/darts/dartsapp/templates
                <Directory /var/www/darts/darts/dartsapp/templates/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                        AllowOverride All
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>
                 Alias /static /var/www/darts/darts/dartsapp/static
                <Directory /var/www/darts/darts/dartsapp/static/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                        AllowOverride All
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>
                 Alias /uploads /var/www/darts/darts/dartsapp/uploads
                 <Directory /var/www/darts/darts/dartsapp/uploads/>
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                        AllowOverride All
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                LogLevel warn
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

darts.wsgi file (under /var/www/darts):

```
#!/var/www/darts/darts/venv/bin/python3.10/
import sys
#sys.path.append('/var/www/darts/darts/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/')

import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/darts/darts/")

from darts import app as application
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to run everything by adding two changes.

The darts.wsgi file now looks like this:

```
#!/var/www/darts/darts/venv/bin/python3.10
import sys
sys.path.append('/var/www/darts/darts/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/')

import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/darts/darts/")
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/darts/darts/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages")

from dartsapp import create_app

application = create_app()
```

and in the darts.conf file I have added

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

Seems to be working for now.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to append the site-packages folder onto the end of the path and then also insert it into the first element of the path.  You can pick one or the other and get the same effect.  My import line looks like this: "from dartsapp import app as application" and doesn't need the next "application = create_app()" line

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I run WSGI in daemon mode then the wsgi file can be really
simple, and the apache config is only a big more complex.

Presuming your apps folder is called darts, and you use `app=Flask(__name__)` to define your app.

```
from darts import app as application
```

Here is the simplified apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName darts.loc
WSGIDaemonProcess darts threads=5 python-home=/var/www/darts/darts/venv python-path=/var/www/darts/
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/darts/dart.wsgi
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
<Directory /var/www/darts/darts>
    WSGIProcessGroup darts
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```