# mod_wsgi Permission error on virutal environment start file

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

When trying to start my python flask project in the mod_wsgi virtual environment I get the following error message:
[Fri Apr 14 16:49:46.261165 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 76114:tid 139906982557248] [client 91.23.91.105:60033] mod_wsgi (pid=76114): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/conjugationgame.de/**init**.wsgi'., referer: https://conjugationgame.de/
[Fri Apr 14 16:49:46.261252 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 76114:tid 139906982557248] [client 91.23.91.105:60033] mod_wsgi (pid=76114): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/conjugationgame.de/**init**.wsgi'., referer: https://conjugationgame.de/
[Fri Apr 14 16:49:46.261396 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 76114:tid 139906982557248] [client 91.23.91.105:60033] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: https://conjugationgame.de/
[Fri Apr 14 16:49:46.261438 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 76114:tid 139906982557248] [client 91.23.91.105:60033]   File "/var/www/conjugationgame.de/**init**.wsgi", line 4, in , referer: https://conjugationgame.de/
[Fri Apr 14 16:49:46.261445 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 76114:tid 139906982557248] [client 91.23.91.105:60033]     with open(activate_this) as file_:, referer: https://conjugationgame.de/
[Fri Apr 14 16:49:46.261464 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 76114:tid 139906982557248] [client 91.23.91.105:60033] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/hfwds/.local/share/virtualenvs/conjugationgame-4RgIZZXj/bin/activate_this.py', referer: https://conjugationgame.de/

What did I do so far:

- I installed apache2 on ubuntu 22.04
- I installed the virutual environment with pipenv install
  althoud I got this error message:
  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied ‘var/www/conjugationgame.de/conjugationgame/._atomic-writelcmrxftk’ the environment was created
- pipenv --venv provided the link to the activation file
- I created the wsgi file accordingly (cannot enter a picture so I enter the text directly)
  *import sys
  sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/conjugationgame.de/conjugationgame')
  activate_this = '/home/hfwds/.local/share/virtualenvs/conjugationgame-4RgIZZXj/bin/activate_this.py'
  with open(activate_this) as file_:
  exec(file_.read(), dict(**file**=activate_this))

from **init** import app as application*

- I updated the config file accordingly:
  *<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerName [www.conjugationgame.de](http://www.conjugationgame.de)
  ServerAlias conjugationgame.de
  DocumentRoot /var/www/conjugationgame.de/conjugationgame
  WSGIDaemonProcess flaskapp user=hfwds group=hfwds processes=2 threads=5
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/conjugationgame.de/**init**.wsgi
  <Directory /var/www/conjugationgame.de/conjugationgame>
  WSGIProcessGroup flaskapp
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all

  Alias /static /var/www/conjugationgame.de/conjugationgame/static
  <Directory /var/www/conjugationgame.de/conjugationgame/static>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/conjugationgame.de_ssl_certificate.cer
  SSLCertificateKeyFile *.conjugationgame.de_private_key.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/*.conjugationgame.de_ssl_certificate_INTERMEDIATE.cer
  ErrorLog /var/www/conjugationgame.de/logs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/conjugationgame.de/logs/access.log combined
   *
- I changed the user to hfwds form www-data
- I changed the authorization of the directy home/hfwds to 755 as proposed in stackoverflow
- I changed the authorization of the activation file to all read writed and execute

I am trying to get information how to overcome this errror to be able to start my python flask project on the web server to be able to access it from any browser.

Comment: Problem solved: As I do not need a virutal environment (thank you @graham dumpleton I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71716933/how-to-structure-apache-virtual-host-and-wsgi-file-for-flask-application-with-py

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: as I do not need a virtual environment (thank you @graham dumpleton I found the solution here:[link to the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71716933/how-to-structure-apache-virtual-host-and-wsgi-file-for-flask-application-with-py)

For single applications the "activate-this" is not necessary. See also [Gramham's explanation virtual environment](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/master/user-guides/virtual-environments.html)